# Insertar fila al final de un Excel C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, .net, linq

¡Buenos días a todos!

Estoy tratando de agregar una nueva fila a un Excel al final de todos los datos.

Como pueden ver, el Excel tiene un encabezado y luego todos los registros del "billingSummary". Al final de este último, me gustaría agregar una fila para calcular los totales.

```
var excelDataRows = new List<ExcelDataTableRow>
    {
        new ExcelDataTableRow
        {
            CellValues = new List<string>
            {
                "Fecha",
                "Contrato",
                "Consorcio",
                "Unidad",
                "Importe Cobrado",
                "Comisión Plataforma",
                "Neto",
                "Factura"
            }
        }
    };

    excelDataRows.AddRange(billingSummary.OrderBy(x => x.PaymentDate)
        .ThenBy(x => x.OwnersAssociationCode)
        .ThenBy(x => x.FunctionalUnitCode)
        .Select(item => new ExcelDataTableRow
        {
            CellValues = new List<string>
            {
                item.PaymentDate.Day.ToString() + '/' + item.PaymentDate.Month.ToString() + '/' + item.PaymentDate.Year.ToString(),
                item.ContractCode.ToString(),
                item.OwnersAssociationCode.ToString(),
                item.FunctionalUnitCode.ToString(),
                item.TotalAmount.ToStringCurrency(),
                item.PlapsaComission.ToStringCurrency(),
                item.NetAmount.ToStringCurrency(),
                item.Type + ' ' + item.PointOfSale + '-' + item.Number,
            }
        }));

    //excelDataRows = new List<ExcelDataTableRow>
    //{
    //    new ExcelDataTableRow
    //    {
    //        CellValues = new List<string>
    //        {
    //            "HOLA",
    //            "CHAU"
    //        }
    //    }
    //};

    return excelDataRows;
```

¡Espero que puedan ayudarme! ¡Gracias!

Comment: Has intentado algo ? Que te impide lograrlo ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yo intenté agregar una nueva fila mostrando "Hola" y "Chau" como ejemplo. Sin embargo, esto me superponía todas las demás filas (la de encabezado y las de registros) por esta nueva fila. (Es el código comentado).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola que pasa en ese código que tiene comentado al setear un nuevo valor a `excelDataRows` está reiniciando el valor de la lista, lo que tiene q usar es el método `Add` que tiene la lista

```
excelDataRows.Add(new ExcelDataTableRow
    {
        CellValues = new List<string>
        {
            "HOLA",
            "CHAU"
        }
    }
); return excelDataRows;
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias! No había intentado eso! Se me paso probarlo así.

Comment: Por nada, me alegra que pudiera resolver su problema